# Making a dashed arrow line in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I want to make a dashed line with an arrow, for UML, like this:

[image]

However in Sketch the border is also getting applied to the arrow, so I am getting an output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make a symbol out of three lines (a long dashed one and two solid ones for arrowheads), using the resizing options to keep the arrowhead in the same position and size:

[image]

Comment: There are also decent libraries with premade symbols, like this one https://sketchflowkit.com/